# Why combining 2 paragraphs doesn't work after slideOut() and slideIn() operation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have 6 paragraphs.
I am animating odd number paragraphs by using a slide animation as follows:

```
$("#buttonBslideup").click(function(){
$("#col2 p:odd").slideUp();
});
```

After this I use slide down animation to bring back the odd paragraphs back to their place as follows:

```
$("#buttonBslidedown").click(function(){
$("#col2 p:odd").slideDown();
});
```

After this if I want to combine the 3rd and 4th paragraphs by clicking another button, it does not work.

```
    $("#buttonCAdd").click(function () {
    $("#col2 .thirdparagraph").addClass("orig");
    $("#col2 .fourthparagraph").addClass("orig");
});
<style>
.orig{
display:inline;
}
</style>
```

If I refresh the page and first press the button to combine the paragraphs, it works fine.
But after slide out and slide in, it doesn't work.

Find the HTML code below :

```
<div id="col2">

<p class="firstparagraph"> firstparagraph </p>
<p class="secondparagraph"> secondparagraph </p>
<p class="thirdparagraph">  thirdparagrap  </p>
<p class="fourthparagraph"> fourthparagraph </p>
<p class="fifthparagraph">  fifthparagraph  </p>
<p class="sixthparagraph">  sixthparagraph  </p>
</div>
```

What could be the reason ? If anyone has any idea, please share.
Or tell some alternate way so that combining should work even after slide operation.

Comment: Please create jsfiddle for this

Comment: Can you please give us some more info about your HTML content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be related to [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules. Those jQuery methods add inline `display` styles to element and inline styles has higher specificity compared to a class selector. The added class rules can't override the inline styles.

Either use the `css` method for setting the `display` property or add `!important` to the CSS property (*the `!important` is considered a bad practice and should be avoided.*)

Comment: Yes it is working with css() method. But why css() method works ? Is it able to override the inline css added by slideUp() and slideDown()

Comment: Thanks the link to CSS specifity is very informative !

Comment: It must be that inline can override inline (since css() method is inline) but class selectors cannot. That's why .css() is working